# ASP.NET - Current name of page from web user control?

Tags: asp.net, controls

I need to find out name of location where web user control is. Somethnig like HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString(), but I get only page for this web user control.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Request.Url.Segments will give you a string array. The last item is the page

Comment: I used this to get the page: `var page = Request.Url.Segments.Last();`

Comment: Last item is the page NAME.

Answer (score 3):

You should try the `Request.Url.LocalPath` property

```
string fileNameFromLocalPath = Path.GetFileName(Request.Url.LocalPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code helps:

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you ask for Page.getType.name, you will get the name of the master, the aspx page.
if you want the name of the ascx control you are working on, use
me.GetType.Name.ToString
if your control is in a directory MyDir and the name of your ascx is test.ascx then the result will be

"ASP.MyDir_test_ascx"

Answer (score 0):

You can also use (VB.Net):

```
Dim pageName as String = Page.GetType().Name
```

which replaces the .extension with an underscore

So from **Default.aspx** you would be returned **Default_aspx**

You can also use:

```
Dim pageName as String = CType(HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler, Page).GetType().Name
```

Which will produce the same results as described above.